# Unmanaged Exports Not Working with RGiesecke.DllExport

Tags: c#, .net

Trying to use this library:
RGiesecke.DllExport

Source:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using RGiesecke.DllExport;
namespace DLLZ
{

class Test
{
    [DllExport("add", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static int TestExport(int left, int right)
    {
        return left + right;
    }
}
}
```

No exported function is showing in the DLL and GetProcAddress on the function/library fails.

[image]

Comment: There are a *lot* of ways to lose with that utility.  Including using the wrong diagnostic tool (use Dumpbin.exe /exports), not having VS elevated when you retrieve the Nuget package and having the project's Platform target set to AnyCPU.

Comment: Ah yes setting to x86 instead of any cpu fixed it. many thanks

Comment: @HansPassant i see your discouraging comments about unmanaged exports, but what is a better solution